# Inconsecutive or nonconsecutive or ...?

Tags: word-choice, adjectives, negation, prefixes

I want to say that the data is not like 154, 155, 156, 157, 158, 159 but can be 154, 156, 157, 159. How do I negate the word "consecutive"? I was not able to find it in the dictionary. I have found both variants but the resource is not very reliable.

Comment: Have you checked the two possible words in the dictionary?

Comment: @Kris have you read my question?

Comment: @Tomas: Using an unreliable dictionary isn't really using a dictionary, is it?

Comment: Did you mention *some* dictionary? I don't see any. https://www.google.com/#q=consecutive+antonym

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The generally accepted version of the word is nonconsecutive, especially where numbers are concerned.

Comment: Thanks, that's a good news for me, because I have to use it in sentence with *"in"*, and *"in inconsecutive years"* would sound really strange :-)

Comment: Generally if it sounds strange to say out loud, it's probably wrong.

Comment: -1 What is the source of this 'information'?

Answer (score 2):

When looking for a more reliable resource, check out the [Corpus of Contemporary American English (COCA)](https://www.english-corpora.org/coca/) and the [British National Corpus (BNC)](https://www.english-corpora.org/bnc/):

```
                   COCA     BNC

nonconsecutive      22       0
non-consecutive      3       2
unconsecutive        1       0
inconsecutive        0       1
```

Do note that due to the relatively small corpus size, BNC won't always be clear in its verdict — as indeed it isn't too clear in this particular case —, so make sure to check both corpora. Especially when writing for an international audience.

Comment: +1 That is because of the context that each fits appropriately into. Most of the time we do mean *non-consecutive*, not *inconsecutive*. (You see they do not mean quite the same thing.)